# Installing two linux distros with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

In my internal hard drive, I have windows 10 and ubuntu 15.10 installed in dual boot mode. But whenever I am trying to install another linux distro(in my case, mint), the ubuntu boot loader fails and i have to plug in the hard drive all time for boot loader to detect all the installed OS.While installing in external hard drive, I always installed the boot loader in external hard drive. My boot mode is UEFI. Boot priority is ubuntu. How to install mint in external hard drive so that it doesn't mess with my previously installed windows 10 and ubuntu in internal hard drive ?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: BIOSes and EFIs boot very differently. You're thinking in BIOS terms.

Long version: In a BIOS, boot code resides in the boot sector of a disk and then in various follow-on locations. Typically, the boot loader for an OS goes on the same physical disk as the OS's main files. Therefore, you can control the boot process by plugging in one disk or another.

Under EFI, boot loaders are stored as ordinary files on a partition called the [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) The ESP might or might not be on the same physical disk as the OS(es). You can also have multiple ESPs -- one per disk, two on one disk and one on another, or whatever. The computer knows which boot loader to use because that information is stored in NVRAM. If you unplug a disk, the NVRAM *may* be cleared of references to boot loader(s) on that disk. (This behavior is a feature of *some* EFIs, but not of all of them.) When you install a new OS, it will typically put its boot loader in an ESP and make it the default boot loader. Which ESP? Good question! Unless you understand and properly control the process, it might as well be random.

GRUB adds a further twist to the picture, because it relies on a configuration file that need not be on the ESP. In the case of both Ubuntu and Mint, the GRUB configuration file goes in the Linux `/boot/grub` directory. If this directory is on a different physical disk than the ESP, and if you unplug that disk, GRUB will fail, presenting a `grub>` prompt and being generally useless. You were unclear about GRUB's failure state, but it sounds like this was it.

Under EFI, it's possible to change the default boot program by using a Linux program called `efibootmgr` -- type `sudo efibootmgr` to see the available boot programs (or `sudo efibootmgr -v` to get more details), then use the `-o` option to re-order them, as in `sudo efibootmgr -o 3,5,0`.

Putting all of this together, chances are you wound up with Ubuntu's GRUB on an ESP on your internal disk with its configuration file on the external disk. You *might* have been able to correct this by using `efibootmgr` to switch back to Mint's GRUB -- but as Mint is basically Ubuntu with bits added, it's likely that Ubuntu's GRUB overwrote Mint's GRUB, so this might not have worked. Using Boot Repair probably restored Mint's GRUB to control of the computer and added Ubuntu to Mint's GRUB menu.

Another option would have been to install another boot loader that doesn't have GRUB's cross-partition dependencies. My own [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is particularly useful in situations like yours, because it scans for boot loaders and kernels at every boot. Thus, if you were to install rEFInd on your internal disk's ESP, it would detect Ubuntu's kerenels if and only if your Ubuntu disk were plugged in. With that disk unplugged, the Ubuntu kernel option would disappear from the menu. (There might be a separate option for launching GRUB, which would probably have an Ubuntu icon.)

Comment: What a great answer, packed with useful information! I'm pretty much in the OP's shoes, I want to install Linux to a WD Elements, not always plugged in. I'll take a close look at rEFind.

Comment: Everything is crystal clear now. Now I understand the difference between UEFI and BIOS modes. It is an amazing answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to set the grub2. Below are the instructions.

Make an ubuntu bootable usb or dvd.
plug it and boot into it. Now enter into `Try Ubuntu`.
Now open terminal and type `sudo su` to get root privileges.
Now type in terminal the following line you can just copy-paste the below lines.

> add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair 
>   apt-get update
>   apt-get install boot-repair

and launch it by typing in terminal `boot-repair`

select the first recommended option

Comment: It worked!!! now pc loads just the way i wanted to..with all the options

Comment: Don't know if it's a write question to ask here or not..but why did it happen ? I installed the boot loader in two separate hard drives..why couldn't GRUB detect installed OSs ?